# C - ctrl Z does not working in Bash Shell on windows 10

Tags: linux, shell, signals

I'm runing a simple program that print numbers in an infinite loop, the code is as follow:

```
int main(){
int i = 0;
while(1){
    printf("i = %d\n", i);
    i++;
    sleep(1);
}
return EXIT_SUCCESS;}
```

After I'm execute the program I'm trying to put it to sleep state using `ctrl Z`, but the program continue to run...

**EDIT:**
has said in the commands, this is a known issue on Windows (version 15063.138), and the guys on Microsoft are working to fix it. Until they manage to fix that and to release another windows version, does someone has an idea on how to work-around this problem and get the `ctrl + z` to work in the meantime?

Comment: Did you try `CTRL` + `C`?

Comment: Do you get *any* output when you press `CTRL-Z`? Or is it just your program printing the value of `i` once every second? How did you start your program?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't get any respose, only a "^Z" print on the screen and the numbers keep printing... I'm using a GCC compiler and then just run the program.. "./prog1" in the terminal

Comment: @mitogh the `ctrl c` is working as usual...

Comment: How about ctrl + D

Comment: @mitogh `ctrl + d` do nothing... `ctrl + \' also nothing...

Comment: Try `kill -SIGSTOP <pid>` from another terminal. Look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/394100/ctrl-c-and-ctrl-z-not-working-in-terminal) as well

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm using the Bash Shell on windows 10 so when I'm try to get the pid in the new terminal, using `ps` command, it don't recognize the "prog1" program, that already run on a different termianl, so I cann't use the kill command

Comment: "Bash Shell on windows 10" is by no means "Linux Shell" as stated in the title.

Comment: Looks like a current issue on windows, see the bottom of https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1569

Comment: @EugeneSh. sorry about the misunderstanding... for clarification I'm using the "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" in windows 10....

Comment: @nos thank you! It seems that this is a problem with the Bash itself... Any suggestions how to "Work-Around" until fixed in the next windows release?